# CSS .not(selector) is not working on a span tag

Tags: html, css

I have a header that contains a span tag with a date in it and some text. The text should be bold the date should stay normal.

In the CSS file I use `:not(cls)` but somehow the date gets formatted too.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.parent:not(.date) {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.date {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="date">the date</span> title goes here
</div>
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

`.parent:not(.date)` means "An element that is a member of the class *parent* and is not a member of the class *data*".

Since you have no elements which have `class="parent date"`, this makes the `:not()` portion pointless.

The selector was never going to apply to the span anyway (because the span doesn't have `class="parent"`).

---

Look at the element in the DOM inspector built into your browser.

[image: DOM inspector screenshot]

The default value for the `font-weight` property on a span element is `inherit`, so it will get whatever the parent element has.

If you don't want it to be bold, then you need to say so explicitly.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.parent {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.date {
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="date">the date</span> title goes here
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could just do it this way as well?

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.date {
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```